# How to create data in a feature and pass it as a parameter to the next feature in Cucumber

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am using a Cucumber POM test automation framework. I have a feature that creates data and I store it on an excel. Is there a way that I can use the data created in my next feature without interacting with excel.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is written straight into excel file, you don't have any workaround for this, you need to access and read the file.
When you generate the data in excel, you can have another "middleman" where to store this data and provide it to other test(s).
Try to use @DataProvider from TestNg to save this data and pass it to other test(s), or if you are using Junit, create your logic to store the data in a collection, has, properties file etc, then use it.